# I need to get all announcements Sharepoint items from all sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to get all announcements items from all sites and display them on home page? how I can do that?

Note: I know I can use **SPSiteDataQuery**, but this object don't allow me to get SPListItems, and it is return a DataTable object with strings columns, I need to get items As SPListItem collection.

what is the best way to do that with good performance, I have 100 subs sites that have announcements lists.

Comment: SiteDataQuery do not return SPListItemCollection. Any specific reason why you need SPListItemCollection?

Comment: the reason is "as SharePoint developer" I'm using SPListItem always when manipulate the SharePoint item. why this time i need to use DataTable object? as example: I'm already built my framework and utilities to work with SPListItem.

Comment: You will get list and item ids in the data table. You can easily create `SPListItem` object from it. Generally, when you are quering data using SiteDataQuery, majority of the time, that is for display/read purpose only. You can easily generate associated form links and redirect/popup item forms within search result ui interface. Short answer to your question is, its not possible, sharepoint doesn's support it :(